# Swift LinkedIn Login: Get Public Profile URL

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the User's LinkedIn *Profile URL* using LinkedIn SDK and Swift 3. I have a functional login but I can't figure out how to retrieve the Profile URL data I requested.

```
self.linkedinHelper.requestURL("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(public-profile-url)?format=json", requestType: LinkedinSwiftRequestGet, success: { (response) -> Void in

print("Request success with response: \(response)")
```

This code prints a success, and I can see the profile URL. I cannot figure out how to extract the URL from the `response` variable. The type of `response` is **`LSResponse`**. How can I get the `public-profile-url` data from the `response` variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `response`'s `jsonData` property in order to access the data in JSON format. According to the [LinkedIn API guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api#), you should access the `url` key inside a dictionary called `siteStandardProfileRequest`.

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [String: Any],
    let siteStandardProfileRequest = json["siteStandardProfileRequest"] as? [String: Any],
    let urlString = siteStandardProfileRequest["url"] as? String,
    let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    let profileUrl = url
}
```